# is there a method on how to count the longest substring or sublist that are the same when mirrored

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

so i need to find whats the longest sublist that can be mirrored, knowing the number of element
ex:

```
n = 5
my_list = [1,2,3,2,1]
```

heres my code:

```
n = int(input())
my_list = list(map(int, input().split()))
c = 0
s1 = my_list
x = 0
i = 0
while i < n:
    s2 = s1[i:]
    if s2 == s2[::-1]:
        if c <= len(s2):
            c = len(s2)
    if i >= n-1:
        i = 0
        n = n - 1
        s1 = s1[:-1]
    i += 1
print(c)
```

as we see the list is the same when mirrored, but when `n = 10` and `my_list = [1,2,3,2,1,332,6597,6416,614,31]` the result is `3` instead of the expected `5`.

Comment: Any constraints on the length of the list? That would be important when coming up with a algorithm.

Comment: sorry i didn't paid attention to the comments much. the length of the list should be ≤ 10⁶, but for a testing case, 10⁴ would do

Comment: The order of n is actually the most important factor here. An O(n^2) solution is pretty easy, but wouldn't be practical if n<=10^6

Comment: then in this case the list can be up to 10⁴ element. hopefully it's enough for what i need

Comment: For [1,2,1,4,2,1], is the answer [1,2,1] or [1,2,1,2,1]?

Comment: should be 1 2 1 because thw order shouldn't get changed

Comment: You should edit the question to mention if you need a subsequence or a subarray

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution would be splitting the array in each iteration into a left and a right array, and then reversing the left array.
Next, compare each element from each array and increment the length variable by one while the elements are the same.

```py
def longest_subarr(a):
    longest_exclude = 0
    for i in range(1, len(a) - 1):
        # this excludes a[i] as the root
        left = a[:i][::-1]
        # this also excludes a[i], needs to consider this in calculation later
        right = a[i + 1:] 

        max_length = min(len(left), len(right))
        length = 0

        while(length < max_length and left[length] == right[length]):
            length += 1
        longest_exclude = max(longest_exclude, length)
    # times 2 because the current longest is for the half of the array
    # plus 1 to include to root
    longest_exclude = longest_exclude * 2 + 1

    longest_include = 0
    for i in range(1, len(a)):
        # this excludes a[i] as the root
        left = a[:i][::-1]
        # this includes a[i]
        right = a[i:] 

        max_length = min(len(left), len(right))
        length = 0

        while(length < max_length and left[length] == right[length]):
            length += 1
        longest_include = max(longest_include, length)
    # times 2 because the current longest is for the half of the array
    longest_include *= 2

    return max(longest_exclude, longest_include)
    
print(longest_subarr([1, 4, 3, 5, 3, 4, 1]))
print(longest_subarr([1, 4, 3, 5, 5, 3, 4, 1]))
print(longest_subarr([1, 3, 2, 2, 1]))
```

This covers test case for odd-length sub-array like `[a, b, a]` and even-length sub-array `[a, b, b, a]`.

Comment: when testing i found your code gave the wrong answer for ```my_list = [1, 3, 2, 2,1]``` will result in 1, but the correct answer shouldve been 2, as the 2 2 elements are the same when reversed.

Comment: ah great test case, i guess the patch to this is to run another comparison with including the root into the array

Answer (score 0):

Since you need the longest sequence that can be mirrored, here is a simple O(n^2) approach for this.
Go to each index, consider it as the center, and expand towards both left and right, one step at a time, if the numbers are equal. Or else break, and move onto the next index.

```
def longest_mirror(my_array): 
    maxLength = 1
  
    start = 0
    length = len(my_array) 
  
    low = 0
    high = 0
  
    # One by one consider every character as center point of mirrored subarray
    for i in range(1, length): 
    # checking for even length subarrays
        low = i - 1
        high = i 
        while low >= 0 and high < length and my_array[low] == my_array[high]: 
            if high - low + 1 > maxLength: 
                start = low 
                maxLength = high - low + 1
            low -= 1
            high += 1
  
        # checking for even length subarrays
        low = i - 1
        high = i + 1
        while low >= 0 and high < length and my_array[low] == my_array[high]: 
            if high - low + 1 > maxLength: 
                start = low 
                maxLength = high - low + 1
            low -= 1
            high += 1
  
    return maxLength
```